# Getting Raspberry pi events from android/iOS app

Tags: android, python, ios, raspberry-pi

I just got started with Raspberry pi and I wanted to make a program on my Raspberry which gets input from an app on my Android/iOS device over bluetooth. I wanted to first check if something like this is possible and second if you have any clues on how to do something like this.
Thanks
PS: Since I just got started I'm only looking for clues and I don't want anyone to write and app for me so don't down vote

Comment: i am doing the same project.. you have couple choices.. build on the Resberry a Server which listen to Post/Get Requests and send them from phone .. or use send requests over Bluetooth but u must have Respbian for Eclipse IOT..

Comment: Thanks @ItzikSamara , I prefer using bluetooth. Are there any tutorials or sources I can get started with? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would likely need to establish a network communication between the Raspberry Pi and the device.

For the server:

```
import socket
HOST = ''                   # This should receive from all available interfaces.
PORT = 1111                 # Random port number.
data = "Test"               # Data to send to the client.


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
while True:
    s.sendto(data, (HOST, PORT))
    print data
```

On the client, very similar code but add:

```
data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
print addr
print "Message received: ", data
```

Under the `while True`

Reference the following for setting up RPI wireless hotspot:
http://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot

The HOST for each is going to be the device IPv4 address, usually in format:
192.168.x.x.

I have not personally found a way without using serials for data communication. The most common way to communicate information between devices is over network. Look into peer-to-peer network solutions.

The code may not work as is, you will need to make client/server-side code specific for your needs.
Reference the following for setting up sockets and a low-level network interface: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html

Hopefully this helps.

**EDIT:**

There is a Bluetooth method for RPI.
Here's a good branch in Github that contains example of the Bluetooth library used in Python:
https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/blob/master/examples/simple

Good references:

*Bluetooth programming with Python.*

http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c212.html

*How to create a Bluetooth tag with RPI.*

https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/create-a-raspberry-pi-3-bluetooth-tag/

Comment: Thanks very much , do you know any solutions using bluetooth?

Comment: @m0j1 I edited my answer to reflect that. There is a Bluetooth library you can look into called PyBluez. It should help you attain what you're looking for. A few Google searches and you'll have plenty of information. I also suggest looking on the Raspberry Pi forums for samples.